# Roslyn : detect if IdentifierName is a property?

Tags: c#, roslyn

With Roslyn how to you know if an IdentifierName SyntaxNode refers to a property in the following example:

```
using System;
namespace test
{
    public class Base {
        public int Data { get {return Data;} set {Data = value;} }
        public int Normal;
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Base b = new Base();
            int x = b.Data;
            int y = b.Normal;
        }
    }
}
```

When I print the SyntaxNode tree the last two assignment expressions look the same.  How do I know that the IdentifierName node for b.Data is a Property?  I've checked the ISymbol, ITypeSymbol and don't see anyway of doing it.

Here is the part of the SyntaxNode tree that I print out.

```
    node[4][1]=LocalDeclarationStatement,declsymbol=null,symbol=null,type=null
      node[5][0]=VariableDeclaration,declsymbol=null,symbol=null,type=null
        node[6][0]=PredefinedType,declsymbol=null,symbol=int,name=Int32,static=False,type=int,static=False,type.Kind=NamedType,type.TypeKind=Struct
        node[6][1]=VariableDeclarator,declsymbol=x,symbol=null,type=null
          node[7][0]=EqualsValueClause,declsymbol=null,symbol=null,type=null
            node[8][0]=SimpleMemberAccessExpression,declsymbol=null,symbol=test.Base.Data,name=Data,static=False,type=int,static=False,type.Kind=NamedType,type.TypeKind=Struct
              node[9][0]=IdentifierName,declsymbol=null,symbol=b,name=b,static=False,type=test.Base,static=False,type.Kind=NamedType,type.TypeKind=Class
              node[9][1]=IdentifierName,declsymbol=null,symbol=test.Base.Data,name=Data,static=False,type=int,static=False,type.Kind=NamedType,type.TypeKind=Struct
    node[4][2]=LocalDeclarationStatement,declsymbol=null,symbol=null,type=null
      node[5][0]=VariableDeclaration,declsymbol=null,symbol=null,type=null
        node[6][0]=PredefinedType,declsymbol=null,symbol=int,name=Int32,static=False,type=int,static=False,type.Kind=NamedType,type.TypeKind=Struct
        node[6][1]=VariableDeclarator,declsymbol=y,symbol=null,type=null
          node[7][0]=EqualsValueClause,declsymbol=null,symbol=null,type=null
            node[8][0]=SimpleMemberAccessExpression,declsymbol=null,symbol=test.Base.Normal,name=Normal,static=False,type=int,static=False,type.Kind=NamedType,type.TypeKind=Struct
              node[9][0]=IdentifierName,declsymbol=null,symbol=b,name=b,static=False,type=test.Base,static=False,type.Kind=NamedType,type.TypeKind=Class
              node[9][1]=IdentifierName,declsymbol=null,symbol=test.Base.Normal,name=Normal,static=False,type=int,static=False,type.Kind=NamedType,type.TypeKind=Struct
```

You can see that the IdentifierName node for Data and Normal look the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because syntax nodes only tell you about the syntax.  The syntax tree is constructed without references; it neither knows nor cares what the names are (or even whether they exist at all).

Instead, you need the Semantic Model, which comes from a compilation.

Get the symbol for the `IdentifierName`, then check whether its `Kind` is `Property` or `Field`.

If the symbol is null, you probably have compilation errors.

Comment: ISymbol.Kind - why didn't I see that.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the ISymbol that is returned from `SemannticModel.GetSymbolInfo` is an [IFieldSymbol](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/IFieldSymbol.cs) or an [IPropertySymbol](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/IPropertySymbol.cs).